# apache mod_jk not working

Tags: server, apache2, tomcat, webmin

I installed the jk module for apache2 and it is enabled (I checked in webmin).

I edited my virtual host configuration file and added this line:

```
JKMount /myweb worker1
```

`workers.properties`:

```
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8080
```

I deployed myweb in a tomcat server running on port 8080.

However when browsing to `localhost/myweb` it's just loading the index from the apache directory root, it is not redirecting to the app deployed in the tomcat.

Am I missing some configurations?

Comment: how did you installed mod-jk?

Comment: sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-jk

Comment: Are you sure the connector on port 8080 is an AJP connector? 8080 is normally HTTP with AJP on 8009. There are plenty of possibilities for why this isn't working. We'd need to see the full httpd.conf.

Comment: @MarkThomas There isn't such file in my apache directory.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485505/multiple-instances-for-tomcat-not-working-100-help/487227#487227) is an examples of how to configure tomcat-apache connector.

You forgot **JkWorkersFile** directive. Add this line:

```
  JkWorkersFile /path/workers.properties
```

where path is where you saved your workers.properties file.

The port defined by:

```
  worker.worker1.port=8080
```

is the port where is listening Tomcat. Check tomcat configuration, usually is 8009.